# How can I create such a table?

Tags: database

I'm in training period and my trainer gave me some database exercises.

I have to make **Project**, **Employee**, **Roles** and **Employee_Projects_Role** tables. Last table has the details of the employees working on a project with a specified role.

The conditions he gave to me are:
1. One employee can work in multiple projects.
2. One employee can not have different roles in same projects.

I made those tables and inserted the data. In **roles**, I had roles Leader, Manager, Developer. I made those tables and entered the data.

He checked my tables and said that  a project have more than 1 leader and 1 manager so I restricted the columns like there wont be same roles in one project but now I can not enter 2 developer to that mapping table in one project.

But a project can obviously has 2 developers. So, If you understand the whole scenario then I want to ask that is that possible to restrict a particular column that it would be having only one leader and manager in one project?

I am not really into database but before assigning me a project work he wants to just brush up my basics. So, I am really confused in that.

Schema for those tables is as following:

1. Project with following fields :
   project_pid - primary key,
   project_name
2. Employee with following fields:
   employee_pid - primary key,
   employee_name,
   gender - M/F,
   salary,
   date_of_joining,
   is_active - Y/N
3. Roles with following fields:
   role_pid - primary key,
   role_name - (team member or leader)
4. Employee_Project_Role with following fields:
   project_xid - foreign key (references table Projects),
   employee_xid - foreign key (references table Employee),
   role_xid - foreign key (references table Roles)

Comment: How about showing us a schema...

Comment: And now what database are you using? MySql, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: First thing remove your name from table names this isn't a good pratice.

Comment: sorry, that was a copy paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement such logic, you need to use procedural language. The easiest way in my opinion is defining a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER role_restrict
ON employee_project_role
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @role VARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @ldr_xid VARCHAR(100)

      SELECT @role_xid = (SELECT role_xid
                          FROM   inserted)

      SELECT @ldr_xid = (SELECT role_xid
                         FROM   roles
                         WHERE  role_name = "leader")

      IF @role = @ldr_xid
         AND (SELECT Count(*) AS cnt
              FROM   employee_project_role
              WHERE  project_xid = (SELECT project_xid
                                    FROM   inserted)
                     AND role_xid = @ldr_xid) > 1
        /* Cancel the insert, there is already a leader in a project.*/
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
  /* Otherwise we insert the record */
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the restriction of 'one role per project' and instead create T-SQL stored procedures to insert and update the project employees.

Basically your table and relationships wouldn't allow this type of complex behaviour. You would have to either create linking tables (not allowed by our manager) or code the logic into T-SQL stored procedures.

T-SQL procedures will allow you to perform the logic:

//psuedo code

```
IF newEmployeeToBeInserted.IsManager AND Project_table.ContainsManager
return errorCode
ELSE doInsert
```

Comment: yupp.. I know that. But is there any other approach just through query?

Comment: By 'query' you mean referential integrity - and no. There is no method just using the schema you have provided as there is no 'one-to-one-except-when-some-condition' relationship... Use T-SQL or trigger as shown in other answer